# Oak Tree Disease

Tags: diseases, oak, discoloration

[image]Several live oak trees in my neighborhood over the past years have become covered in these protruding black spots on the bark. When the trees have it for a long time, they look like the tree I posted above. Does anyone know what this is or of we should be concerned? Thank you. [image]

Comment: Where is it located ?

Comment: It is South Florida.

Comment: I think the black spots may be normal, and the rest of the tree is covered with greenish lichen